# The binary operation of division of nonzero rational number is associative or not

Tags: group-theory

The binary operation of division of nonzero rational number is associative or not.                                                           I tried to solve this but I'm little bit confusing due to the operation is division of nonzero rational.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You are trying to determine whether or not $$x/(y/z) = (x/y)/z$$
for all nonzero rationals $x,y,z$.